# App cannot find path on a Mac (works on Win under similar conditions)

Tags: php, macos, path, file-exists

I developed an app for localhost use on a Windows computer (previously with MAMP, not using XAMPP all around). Same app on a Mac where it is intended to be used cannot find the log files I need to open from local directories.

Config:

```
// live/development specific settings
if(LIVE) {
    // If site in live mode
    define('SPOOLER_LOG_FILE', '/opt/program_name/var/tmp/logfile.log');
} else {
    // If site is in development mode
    define('SPOOLER_LOG_FILE', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/logfile.log');
}
```

So yes, I have the actual paths detected and put into the app for both Windows development and Mac live environment.

Where the code gets stuck (works on Windows, cannot find the logfile on Mac):

```
// Get the log file location and Load the log file contents into an array
if(file_exists(SPOOLER_LOG_FILE)) {
    $spooler_log_array = load_tabbed_file(SPOOLER_LOG_FILE);
} else {
    die('LOG NOT FOUND!');
}
```

Note: the load_tabbed_file() function simply reads a tab separated file into an array to be used later (= irrelevant for this issue).

So, file_exists() function seems to be stopping everything since it cannot find the file (I also tried to run load_tabbed_file() directly without file_exists() and that also doesn't work so probably it is the path at fault).

The path on a Mac I navigated to the file and copied the path that the Finder was giving me. I know there should be absolute path used and I really am not sure if the path I used is correct or if the issue might lie elsewhere.

I sincerely hope this is a small issue and someone here could point me in the right direction. After some searching around I am none the wiser and would gladly skip spending hours upon hours to get the paths working on the Mac environment if anyone could help...

Comment: Do you get an error message

Comment: So _Silly Question_ Does the directory `/opt/program_name/var/tmp` exit?

Comment: @RiggsFolly no error message, file_exist() simply returns false as it cannot find the folder. Yes, the folder does exist in reality and has the log file in it (I used Finder and Show Path Bar to copy the logfile path). Note: program_name and logfile name changed for display here. It is a log file created by a printer ripping software. As far as I can tell it is not protected to explain PHP not finding it. CHMOD is 777 for the folder (I checked this). This should allow sufficient access, I believe. Not so sure about any other rights but I can open the log file with textedit.

Comment: At the moment I am thinking that the problem might lie that the folders I am trying to access are located OUTSIDE of the XAMPP htdocs folders (/opt/lampp/htdocs/app for program vs /opt/program_name/var/tmp/logfile.log for the log I need to access). If I copied the log file to /opt/lampp/htdocs root then I can access it with a relative path "../logfile.log". Now the question is how to either force a working absolute path (/opt/program_name/var/tmp/logfile.log obviously is not working though that is the real absolute path) or I need to figure out if and how to use a relative path that works.

Comment: Also tried symlinks. They create just fine but won't work, either. Only thing so far that has worked has been copying the log file under htdocs but IRL that is not an option (unless some 3rd party tool is used for doing that).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out XAMPP by default gives you a VM (Virtual Machine) download and I wasn't even aware they have a separate installer before I was informed of it. Grabbed that, installed, everything works...